# Why is my new toilet running so much?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, toilet

Toilet is only several months old and now it's running like crazy. The water leaks into the bowel all day. Been weeks now, and for some reason it leaves dirt streaks on the bowel from tank. The trickle is so loud, something has to be done.

[image: here is Pic of inside tank]

update: week later, my other bathroom toilet stopped working (no water goes into tank), im thinking all this is because of the sediment that came with the water.

Comment: There is a lot of sediment in the tank for a new toilet.

Comment: Toilet water leaking into the bowel sounds pretty awful. All day you say? Yeesh!

Comment: yeah its very sad

Comment: With that much sediment on a pubic water system I would file a complaint. The sediment probably has plugged the fill valve on the second toilet , some can be "flushed out" by turning off the supply removing the top of the valve and placing a container over the fill valve and turning the water back on once the valve is clear turn water off and reassemble, I see this all the time on homes on a well but not often on city water supplies.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the amount of scum/sediment on the bottom of that tank, I'd bet just cleaning the mating surfaces between the flapper and the outflow drain will solve the problem. And if it only took a few months to get that scummy, you'll want to plan on cleaning these parts regularly—this is especially prudent if you're on septic.

Side note: You might want to look into why your water has so much sediment in suspension. Are you on well water, by any chance?

Comment: it's an apartment in city. Months ago I wanted to buy pump because water wasn't strong enough. But the taps and shower head get blocked and ruined because of it. But this sediment in toilet appeared only month ago all at once. It was clean before. Maybe there is a problem? How do I clean it?

Comment: @Altoban I think it would be sufficient to get a basic scouring pad, like you'd clean dishes with, and scrub clean the underside of your flapper and the mouth of the outflow drain. You probably don't even need a chemical product, I expect scrubbing it will be enough. Scrub it until it no longer feels "slippery".

Comment: new update, my other bathroom toilet stopped working (no water goes into tank), im thinking all this is because of the sediment that came with the water. Should i scrub it or wait till a plumper comes check to see whats happening, because he might not believe it ?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like your water has an issue and I think you're starting to see compounding effects. You definitely need to address the water quality issue, and probably need to contact the utility to initiate that process. It's worth mentioning that any fixture or appliance that is taking in unfiltered water is getting compromised by this water quality, that could include expensive stuff like the water heater! You could install a "whole house" (or in this case apartment) water filter which should help, but that would be a sincere project deserving of a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't like assuming, so here are a couple suggestions...

If your handle, chain or linkage are free and clear, not causing problem with the flapper then it's likely the flapper needs replacing. I have seen times when handle is defective and the chain ended up between the flapper and flush valve, so if handle and chain aren't problem likely the flapper

Question: Are you using chlorine drop-ins designed to keep tank, bowl clean? If so, remove them and DON'T USE THEM EVER AGAIN. Chlorine eats rubber. I've had to change many flappers on brand new homes because of these things. Good for me but bad for my customers. When you touch the flapper if it is real slimy or the rubber stains your fingers, blame chlorine,either over-chlorinated water or drop ins.

One other thing. The thin rubber, plastic tube coming off of your ballcock, and goes to the overflow tube, is it shoved down into the overflow tube or is it clipped just above the top of tube? It should not extend below the water line or it will siphon water and cause ballcock to turn on and off periodically.

You can also turn the supply valve off after tank is full then use a pencil, mark water level, don't flush toilet, come back in 15 minutes and see if water level dropped...if it did, replace the Flapper.

If you are not sure how to remove and replace the flapper be sure to google the toilet and find out proper removal....most are currently mmon sense but these days there are so many manufacturers that it will save headaches to do a quick check.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, new updates, my other bathroom toilet stopped working (no water goes into tank), im thinking all this is because of the sediment that came with the water. For the flapper, i still dont know if thats the cause, but are all flappers the same, or do i need to contact manufacturer?

Comment: I cleaned it throughly, the flapper when I touch it leaves black stains but otherwise is in good condition. The tube is well above the waterline, the issue is the rubber flapper is designed so thin that it hits the corner and folds a tiny bit at one end, allowing water in. The flapper sits on the hole to seal it like a hat. If I use my fingers to press on it at the corners it can stop the water leak if I don't flush again.